# Header image doesn't go full width

Tags: html, css, wordpress

For some reason the header image doesn't go to the full width of my laptop. It does however on the sizes small to medium (mobile phones to laptops). But it doesn't go further than that. This is the code i'm using:

```css
img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-image">
  <a href="http://www.danielbloemendal.nl/" rel="home">
    <img src="http://www.danielbloemendal.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/cropped-IMG_20171002_114642.jpg" srcset="https://i2.wp.com/www.danielbloemendal.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/cropped-IMG_20171002_114642.jpg?w=1200 1200w, https://i2.wp.com/www.danielbloemendal.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/cropped-IMG_20171002_114642.jpg?resize=300%2C70 300w, https://i2.wp.com/www.danielbloemendal.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/cropped-IMG_20171002_114642.jpg?resize=768%2C179 768w, https://i2.wp.com/www.danielbloemendal.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/cropped-IMG_20171002_114642.jpg?resize=1024%2C239 1024w"
      sizes="(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 81vw, (max-width: 1362px) 88vw, 1200px" width="1200" height="280" alt="Staman Steel">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You have explicit widths defined in your `width` attribute and `srcset` will prompt the browser to render the version it deems best for the given resolution.

Comment: I'd remove the php and wordpress tag

Comment: To make header image full width you just need to add css to your header img tag to width:100%;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.header-image img{width:100%; height:auto;}
```

```html
<div class="header-image">
    <a href="http://www.danielbloemendal.nl/" rel="home">
        <img src="http://www.danielbloemendal.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/cropped-IMG_20171002_114642.jpg" srcset="https://i2.wp.com/www.danielbloemendal.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/cropped-IMG_20171002_114642.jpg?w=1200 1200w, https://i2.wp.com/www.danielbloemendal.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/cropped-IMG_20171002_114642.jpg?resize=300%2C70 300w, https://i2.wp.com/www.danielbloemendal.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/cropped-IMG_20171002_114642.jpg?resize=768%2C179 768w, https://i2.wp.com/www.danielbloemendal.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/cropped-IMG_20171002_114642.jpg?resize=1024%2C239 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 81vw, (max-width: 1362px) 88vw, 1200px" width="1200" height="280" alt="Staman Steel">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea never mind, I'm retarded and didn't see that it's not in a style tag. My bad ^^" saw it just before you answered as well

Comment: @AlexEggers Styles declared this way will over-qualify any width set using a `width` attribute - *if* they were set using *inline* style attribute (e.g: `style="width: 1200px;"`) then it wouldn't. If you expand the code snippet to full screen you will notice it is larger than `1200px` - *Edit* just noticed your comment Alex, seems you understand - all good :)

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError not enough coffee :D

Comment: @ravipatel I see it works with your snippet, but it doesn't seem to work on my website. I did exactly what your answer described, but the image doesn't go full width.

Comment: @Bear Please share your url so we can review for suggestion.

Comment: .header-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
} tested on your site using console.

Answer (score 0):

If you look through the IMG tag, you will see that you have defined width, probably to fit it to the screen. If you set this value to 100%, it will stretch. Keep in mind that this will reduce the quality of the image, and you may want to look deeper into the img tag to look for solutions.

EDIT: Just an FYI, you really want to avoid using inline styles, not only but also because they make spotting stuff like this hell if you just look at the text as is.

Comment: The code behind the img is already on 100%:                                       img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

Comment: EDIT: Also, your css has only set a MAX width. The image itself is setting width itself, meaning it will go to that width, not up to that width.

Comment: Disregard what I said, you were not using inline styles, only the width and height attributes of the img tag. Not enough coffee. Nonetheless, your css has only set a MAX width. The image itself is setting width itself, meaning it will go to that width, not up to that width.

Answer (score 0):

Failing to see the CSS that you are using I would say that the image has a fixed width and maybe your laptop width viewport is greater than this resolution width. You have to set the image to 100% with CSS to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

try this : For desktop.

```css
img {
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-image">
  <a href="http://www.danielbloemendal.nl/" rel="home">
    <img src="http://www.danielbloemendal.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/cropped-IMG_20171002_114642.jpg" srcset="https://i2.wp.com/www.danielbloemendal.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/cropped-IMG_20171002_114642.jpg?w=1200 1200w, https://i2.wp.com/www.danielbloemendal.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/cropped-IMG_20171002_114642.jpg?resize=300%2C70 300w, https://i2.wp.com/www.danielbloemendal.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/cropped-IMG_20171002_114642.jpg?resize=768%2C179 768w, https://i2.wp.com/www.danielbloemendal.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/cropped-IMG_20171002_114642.jpg?resize=1024%2C239 1024w"
      sizes="(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 81vw, (max-width: 1362px) 88vw, 1200px" width="1200" height="280" alt="Staman Steel">
  </a>
</div>
```